# How to get the tikz graph library to position nodes nicely

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, graphs

I am trying to draw a picture like this:

[image]

which I have done with the code below (see "tikz listing A"). But I would like to just declare the nodes inside the `graph` section, like the TikZ manual does (section 5.4.2 "Creating Nodes Using the Graph Command"). Unfortunately it looks awful; see below, code is in "tikz listing B"... is there a way I can fix?

[image]

The relevant `graph` code is here, but I can't figure out how to get it to branch nice and symmetrically (and never go back upwards).

```
\graph [grow down, branch right] {
s1[seqpoint, as=1] -> s2[seqpoint, as=2] -> foo[func] -> s3[seqpoint,as=3] -> s9[seqpoint, as=9];  
s1 -> s4[seqpoint, as=4] -> bar1[func, as=bar] -> s5[seqpoint, as=5] -> s9;
s1 -> s6[seqpoint, as=6] -> bar2[func, as=bar] -> s7[seqpoint, as=7] -> baz[func] -> s8[seqpoint, as=8] -> s9 ;
s9 -> s10[seqpoint, as=10] -> tweedledee[func] -> s11[seqpoint, as=11] -> tweedledum[func] -> s12[seqpoint, as=12] -> s13[seqpoint, as=13];
};
```

tikz listing A:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc, graphs, fit, backgrounds, positioning}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,0.8,0}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.8,1.0,0.533}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,thick,black!50,text=black,
every new ->/.style={shorten >=0pt},
seqpoint/.style={
  rectangle,minimum size=4mm,rounded corners=2mm,
  inner sep=0,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=myorange,
  font=\footnotesize\sffamily
},
func/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=mygreen,
  font=\ttfamily
},
parentfunc/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  font=\ttfamily,
  append after command={node[below right = 3pt of \tikzlastnode.north west, font=\ttfamily] {#1}}
},
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners}]
\matrix[column sep=4mm, row sep=4mm] { 
& \node (s1) [seqpoint] {1}; & \\
\node (s2) [seqpoint] {2}; & \node (s4) [seqpoint] {4}; & \node (s6) [seqpoint] {6};\\
\node (foo) [func] {foo}; & \node (bar1) [func] {bar}; & \node (bar2) [func] {bar};\\
\node (s3) [seqpoint] {3}; & \node (s5) [seqpoint] {5}; & \node (s7) [seqpoint] {7};\\
& & \node (baz) [func] {baz};\\
& & \node (s8) [seqpoint] {8};\\
& \node (s9) [seqpoint] {9}; &\\
& \node (quuxspace) []{}; & \\
& \node (s10) [seqpoint] {10}; &\\
& \node (tweedledee) [func] {tweedledee}; &\\
& \node (s11) [seqpoint] {11}; &\\
& \node (tweedledum) [func] {tweedledum}; &\\
& \node (s12) [seqpoint] {12}; &\\
& \node (s13) [seqpoint] {13}; &\\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node (quux) [parentfunc=quux, fill=mygreen!20, fit=(quuxspace) (s13) (tweedledee) (tweedledum)] {};
\node (isr) [parentfunc=isr, fit=(s1) (quux) (foo) (bar2)]{};
\end{scope}
\graph [use existing nodes] {
s1 -> s2 -> foo -> s3 -> s9;  
s1 -> s4 -> bar1 -> s5 -> s9;
s1 -> s6 -> bar2 -> s7 -> baz -> s8 -> s9 ;
s9 -> s10 -> tweedledee -> s11 -> tweedledum -> s12 -> s13;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

tikz listing B:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc, graphs, fit, backgrounds, positioning}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,0.8,0}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.8,1.0,0.533}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,black!50,text=black,
seqpoint/.style={
  rectangle,minimum size=4mm,rounded corners=2mm,
  inner sep=0,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=myorange,
  font=\footnotesize\sffamily
},
func/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=mygreen,
  font=\ttfamily
},
parentfunc/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  font=\ttfamily,
  append after command={node[below right = 3pt of \tikzlastnode.north west, font=\ttfamily] {#1}}
},
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners}]
%\begin{scope}[on background layer]
%\node (quux) [parentfunc=quux, fill=mygreen!20, fit=(quuxspace) (s13) (tweedledee) (tweedledum)] {};
%\node (isr) [parentfunc=isr, fit=(s2) (quux) (foo) (bar2)]{};
%\end{scope}
\graph [grow down, branch right] {
s1[seqpoint, as=1] -> s2[seqpoint, as=2] -> foo[func] -> s3[seqpoint,as=3] -> s9[seqpoint, as=9];  
s1 -> s4[seqpoint, as=4] -> bar1[func, as=bar] -> s5[seqpoint, as=5] -> s9;
s1 -> s6[seqpoint, as=6] -> bar2[func, as=bar] -> s7[seqpoint, as=7] -> baz[func] -> s8[seqpoint, as=8] -> s9 ;
s9 -> s10[seqpoint, as=10] -> tweedledee[func] -> s11[seqpoint, as=11] -> tweedledum[func] -> s12[seqpoint, as=12] -> s13[seqpoint, as=13];
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh, I might have figured it out... I guess it's using the `{}` mechanism for splitting graphs (p. 71 of tikz manual)

Answer (score 2):

Aha, I figured it out: it's the use of `{}` for graph splits, and also `nodes=[xshift]` to get it to adjust nodes leftwards within the split.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, graphs, fit, backgrounds, positioning}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,0.8,0}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.8,1.0,0.533}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,black!50,text=black,
seqpoint/.style={
  rectangle,minimum size=4mm,rounded corners=2mm,
  inner sep=0,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=myorange,
  font=\footnotesize\sffamily
},
func/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  fill=mygreen,
  font=\ttfamily
},
parentfunc/.style={
  rectangle,minimum width=16mm,rounded corners=1mm,
  thick,draw=black!50,
  font=\ttfamily,
  append after command={node[below right = 3pt of \tikzlastnode.north west, font=\ttfamily] {#1}}
},
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners}]
\graph [grow down sep, branch right=20mm] {
s1[seqpoint, as=1] -> { [nodes={xshift=-20mm}]
s2[seqpoint, as=2] -> foo[func] -> s3[seqpoint,as=3],
s4[seqpoint, as=4] -> bar1[func, as=bar] -> s5[seqpoint, as=5],
s6[seqpoint, as=6] -> bar2[func, as=bar] -> s7[seqpoint, as=7] -> baz[func] -> s8[seqpoint, as=8]
}
-> s9[seqpoint, as=9] -- quuxspace[coordinate] -> s10[seqpoint, as=10] -> tweedledee[func] -> s11[seqpoint, as=11] -> tweedledum[func] -> s12[seqpoint, as=12] -> s13[seqpoint, as=13];
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node (quux) [parentfunc=quux, fill=mygreen!20, fit=(quuxspace) (s13) (tweedledee) (tweedledum)] {};
\node (isr) [parentfunc=isr, fit=(s1) (quux) (foo) (bar2)]{};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```